Google Tag Manager suddenly stopped working in Next.JS
I had working Google Tag Manager on a website lochy.pub implemented using GoogleTagManager component from @next/third-parties/google and embedded in pages/_app.tsx
This worked just fine for six months and suddenly stopped working on 4th of July 2024 - no new data received since. Checked the commits and there was no code change around that time, it just stopped working silently. Any ideas what could cause this issue?

